# Using openMP to get the index of minimum element parallelly

Tags: c++, openmp

I tried to write this code

```
float* theArray; // the array to find the minimum value
int   index, i;
float thisValue, min;

index    = 0;
min = theArray[0];
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min:min_dist)
for (i=1; i<size; i++) {
    thisValue = theArray[i];
    if (thisValue < min)

    { /* find the min and its array index */

        min = thisValue;

        index    = i;
    }
}
return(index);
```

However this one is not outputting correct answers. Seems the min is OK but the correct index has been destroyed by threads.

I also tried some ways provided on the Internet and here (using parallel for for outer loop and use critical for final comparison) but this cause a speed drop rather than speedup.

What should I do to make both the min value and its index correct? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it bad to share variables (thisValue, min) between threads without a mutex?

Comment: Seems like this reduction did a lot things, so I'm not so clear whether it is shared or not. I have tried a version without reduction, threads run freely ,the assign part is critical, and the running speed actually goes down.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know of an elegant want to do a minimum reduction and save an index. I do this by finding the local minimum and index for each thread and then the global minimum and index in a critical section.

```
index = 0;
min = theArray[0];
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int index_local = index;
    float min_local = min;  
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {        
        if (theArray[i] < min_local) {
            min_local = theArray[i];
            index_local = i;
        }
    }
    #pragma omp critical 
    {
        if (min_local < min) {
            min = min_local;
            index = index_local;
        }
    }
}
```

With OpenMP 4.0 it's possible to use user-defined reductions. A user-defined minimum reduction can be defined like this

```
struct Compare { float val; sizt_t index; };    
#pragma omp declare reduction(minimum : struct Compare : omp_out = omp_in.val < omp_out.val ? omp_in : omp_out)
```

Then the reduction can be done like this

```
struct Compare min; 
min.val = theArray[0]; 
min.index = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(minimum:min)
for(int i = 1; i<size; i++) {
    if(theArray[i]<min.val) { 
        min.val = a[i];
        min.index = i;
    }
}
```

That works for C and C++. User defined reductions have other advantages besides simplified code. There are multiple algorithms for doing reductions. For example the merging can be done in `O(number of threads)` or `O(Log(number of threads)`. The first solution I gave does this in `O(number of threads)` however using user-defined reductions let's OpenMP choose the algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I'm getting incorrect results with this code.

Comment: Got it. `theArray[i] < min` should be `theArray[i] < min_local`. +1 for being faster than the optimized non-OMP version.

Comment: I'm also getting incorrect results with this code. DId you fix that, Avi?

Comment: @xxbidiao As of when you posted your comment, the code was corrected.

Comment: Very nice edit. Clean and clear. Now, to benchmark... (not today...).

Comment: @AviGinsburg, thanks. I don't think it will make a difference in performance. Although OpenMP could merge in O(Log(nthreads)) I think in practice O(threads) wins because of the overhead to merge in O(Log(nthreads)) is much higher. But it would be interesting to find a case where it makes a difference. Maybe on the GPU OpenMP will merge O(Log(nthreads)) ...

Comment: Add `initializer(omp_priv = {INT_MAX, -1})` to the reduction declaration in order for it to work. It should all be
        ``#pragma omp declare reduction(minimum : struct Compare : \
        omp_out = omp_in.val < omp_out.val ? omp_in : omp_out) \
        initializer(omp_priv = {INT_MAX, -1})``

Answer (score 4):

**Basic Idea**

This can be accomplished without any parellelization-breaking `critical` or `atomic` sections by creating a [custom reduction](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html). Basically, define an object that stores both the index and value, and then create a function that sorts two of these objects by only the value, not the index.

**Details**

An object to store an index and value together:

```
typedef std::pair<unsigned int, float> IndexValuePair;
```

You can access the index by accessing the `first` property and the value by accessing the `second` property, i.e.,

```
IndexValuePair obj(0, 2.345);
unsigned int ix = obj.first;  // 0
float val = obj.second; // 2.345
```

Define a function to sort two `IndexValuePair` objects:

```
IndexValuePair myMin(IndexValuePair a, IndexValuePair b){
    return a.second < b.second ? a : b;
}
```

Then, construct a custom reduction following the guidelines in the OpenMP [documentation](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html):

```
#pragma omp declare reduction \
(minPair:IndexValuePair:omp_out=myMin(omp_out, omp_in)) \
initializer(omp_priv = IndexValuePair(0, 1000))
```

In this case, I've chosen to initialize the index to 0 and the value to 1000. The value should be initialized to some number larger than the largest value you expect to sort.

**Functional Example**

Finally, combine all these pieces with the parallel for loop!

```
// Compile with g++ -std=c++11 -fopenmp demo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<unsigned int, float> IndexValuePair;

IndexValuePair myMin(IndexValuePair a, IndexValuePair b){
    return a.second < b.second ? a : b;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<float> vals {10, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0, -1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8};
    unsigned int i;

    IndexValuePair minValueIndex(0, 1000);

    #pragma omp declare reduction \
        (minPair:IndexValuePair:omp_out=myMin(omp_out, omp_in)) \
        initializer(omp_priv = IndexValuePair(0, 1000))

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(minPair:minValueIndex)
    for(i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++){

        if(vals[i] < minValueIndex.second){
            minValueIndex.first = i;
            minValueIndex.second = vals[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "minimum value = " << minValueIndex.second << std::endl;   // Should be -1
    std::cout << "index = " << minValueIndex.first << std::endl;    // Should be 6


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not only trying to find the minimal value (`reduction(min:___)`) but also retain the index, you need to make the check critical. This can significantly slow down the loop (as reported). In general, make sure that there is enough work so you don't encounter overhead as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473445/openmp-parallel-spiking) question. An alternative would be to have each thread find the minimum and it's index and save them to a unique variable and have the master thread do a final check on those as in the following program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <omp.h>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

void initializeVector(vector<double>& v)
{
    std::mt19937 generator(time(NULL));
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dis(0.0, 1.0);
    v.resize(100000000);
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        v[i] = dis(generator);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> vec;
    initializeVector(vec);

    float minVal = vec[0];
    int minInd = 0;

    int startTime = clock();

    for(int i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(vec[i] < minVal)
        {
            minVal = vec[i];
            minInd = i;
        }

    }

    int elapsedTime1 = clock() - startTime;

    // Change the number of threads accordingly
    vector<float> threadRes(4, std::numeric_limits<float>::max());
    vector<int>   threadInd(4);

    startTime = clock();
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        {
            if(vec[i] < threadRes[omp_get_thread_num()])
            {
                threadRes[omp_get_thread_num()] = vec[i];
                threadInd[omp_get_thread_num()] = i;
            }
        }

    }

    float minVal2 = threadRes[0];
    int minInd2 = threadInd[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < threadRes.size(); i++)
    {
        if(threadRes[i] < minVal2)
        {
            minVal2 = threadRes[i];
            minInd2 = threadInd[i];
        }
    }

    int elapsedTime2 = clock() - startTime;

    cout << "Min " << minVal << " at " << minInd << " took " << elapsedTime1 << std::endl;
    cout << "Min " << minVal2 << " at " << minInd2 << " took " << elapsedTime2 << std::endl;
}
```

Please note that with optimizations on and nothing else to be done in the loop, the serial version seems to remain king. With optimizations turned off, OMP gains the upper hand.

P.S. you wrote `reduction(min:min_dist)` and the proceeded to use min instead of `min_dist`.

Comment: false sharing and `clock`

Comment: @Zboson I'll admit the false sharing point, but `clock` is good enough as the vector size is large enough. If it makes that much of a difference, I'll change it to `chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: [Don't use `clock()` for timing multi-threaded code except with MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874214/measure-execution-time-in-c-openmp-code). Use `omp_get_wtime()` as it's reliable with MSVC, GCC, and ICC.

Comment: @Zboson Thanks, I've never had that issue but will keep it in mind.

Comment: I think there is a way to do this using the reduction construct with OpenMP4.0 by creating custom reductions and operation overloading with C++. But you're using MSVC? It only supports OpenMP 2.0.

Comment: I updated my answer using a user-defined reduction from OpenMP 4.0. I just figured out how to get this working. I think it's a much better solution.

Comment: I'm on GCC. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can use `omp critical` directive to make only one thread run the code inside the critical region at a time.So only one thread can run it and the indexvalue wont be destroyed by other threads.

About omp critical directive:

> The omp critical directive identifies a section of code that must be executed by a single thread at a time.

This code solves your issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main() {
int i;
int arr[10] = {11,42,53,64,55,46,47, 68, 59, 510};

float* theArray; // the array to find the minimum value
int   index;
float thisValue, min;
index    = 0;
min = arr[0];
int size=10;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=1; i<size; i++) {
    thisValue = arr[i];
    #pragma omp critical
    if (thisValue < min)

    { /* find the min and its array index */

        min = thisValue;

        index    = i;
    }
}
printf("min:%d index:%d",min,index);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to bring to your attention that 1) both your code and the OP's code contain a data race/data races. In your case, this can easily be solved by using, for example, `const float thisValue = arr[i];` or just by removing this variable. 2) The bigger issue is that your code runs sequentially (and has parallel overhead), making it slower than the original serial code.